# How to read JSON message in request on RESTful service side.

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I'm trying to read JSON data sent from a client on a service. 
Whatever I try I'm getting an empty object in the console. 
//My service

```
 @Path("signup")
    public class signupservice {


          @POST
          @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          public JSONObject Signmeup( JSONObject inputJsonObj) throws JSONException {

            String fname  = inputJsonObj.toString();   
            System.out.println(fname);   
            JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
            outputJsonObj.put("output", "output");
            return outputJsonObj;
          }
    }
```

I'm sending the request from postman.[image: Postman setup]

Comment: What do you have in Body of request ?

Comment: {
    "first_name" : "datta",
    "last_name"  : "vamshi"
}

Comment: @mismanc can you provide me with an example.

Comment: I want to send the JSON message body with out  using url encoding

Comment: which lib you are using for JSONObject?

Comment: @TumuluriVDattaVamshi I think you want to get first_name and last_name from JSON that you send from client on a service. Is that correct?

Comment: @user3441151 Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @RequestBody annotation to read posted data from Request header

```
  public JSONObject Signmeup(@RequestBody String inputJsonObj) throws {
//your code
    }
```

Comment: I cant find "@RequestBody" tag.

Comment: Try with importing this **org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody** package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get first_name and last_name from JSON that you send from client on a service. You can try this.

```
@Path("signup")
public class signupservice {
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject Signmeup(String inputJsonObj) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject innerJson = new JSONObject(inputJsonObj);
        //Get first_name and last_name from JSON
        String fname  = innerJson.getString("first_name");
        String lname  = innerJson.getString("last_name");
        System.out.println(fname);
        System.out.println(lname);

        JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
        outputJsonObj.put("output", "output");
        return outputJsonObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["first_name"] not found.

Comment: @TumuluriVDattaVamshi Do `sysout` inside your `Signmeup` method of `inputJsonObj` and show me what you get inside `sysout`? Like `System.out.println("inputJsonObj : " + inputJsonObj);`

Comment: @TumuluriVDattaVamshi I just update my answer. You can try this.

Comment: @TumuluriVDattaVamshi I just change the `JSONObject inputJsonObj` into `String inputJsonObj`

Comment: @TumuluriVDattaVamshi Is this has been fixed?

Comment: In sysout "{}" is the output if i print json.toString

Comment: @TumuluriVDattaVamshi Have you implement my updated answer? Just change the `JSONObject inputJsonObj` into `String inputJsonObj` and `@Consumes("application/json")`